# How to tailor R plot axis?

Tags: r

I have the following data stored in a CSV file.

```
NodeID,pageRank
0,0.0327814931593
1,0.384378430034
2,0.342932804288
3,0.0390870921
4,0.0808856932345
5,0.0390870921
```

I have read the CSV file in R and ordered `pageRank` values in descending order.

```
data <- read.csv("pagerank.csv")
data <- data[order(-data$pageRank),]
```

After ordering, `data` look following.

```
1 0.38437843
2 0.34293280
4 0.08088569
3 0.03908709
5 0.03908709
0 0.03278149
```

In the above example, the first column represents `NodeID` (not sequentially ordered) and the second column represents `pageRank` (descending order). Next I have used following command to plot the data.

```
plot(data$pageRank, type="o", col="red", xlab="Node Rank", ylab="PageRank Value")
```

The plot is showing Y-axis (`pageRank` values) properly. However, on the X-axis it is showing sequential numbers (0,1,2,3,4,5). Hence, instead of showing sequential number, how can I plot `NodeID` (1,2,4,3,5,0) on the X-axis (available in `data`) by maintaining `pageRank`'s descending order. I have tried the following. However, it does not maintain `pageRank`'s descending order.

```
plot(data$NodeID, data$pageRank, type="o", col="red", xlab="NodeID", ylab="PageRank Value")
```

Comment: Are you only looking for `base` R answers? If possible, using `ggplot2` would make this much simpler

Comment: Could you please provide me an example?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`fct_reorder`](https://blog.rstudio.com/2016/08/31/forcats-0-1-0/) from the `forcats` package to do the ordering for you. See also [this](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/factors.html).

```r
library(magrittr)
library(tidyverse)
library(forcats)

txt <- "NodeID,pageRank
0,0.0327814931593
1,0.384378430034
2,0.342932804288
3,0.0390870921
4,0.0808856932345
5,0.0390870921"

df <- read_csv(txt)

# Convert NodeID column to factor first
df %<>% 
  mutate(NodeID = factor(NodeID))

# Plot
ggplot(df, aes(pageRank, fct_reorder(NodeID, pageRank))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(aes(y = NodeID, yend = NodeID, x = 0, xend = pageRank), color = "red") +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  ylab("Node Rank") +
  xlab("PageRank Value") +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(df, aes(y = pageRank, x = fct_reorder(NodeID, -pageRank))) +
  geom_line(group = 1, color = "red") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  xlab("Node Rank") +
  ylab("PageRank Value") +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

Using base R plot

```r
df$NodeID <- factor(df$NodeID, levels = c("1", "2", "4", "3", "5", "0"))
plot(df$pageRank ~ df$NodeID, xlab = "Node Rank", ylab = "PageRank Value")
```

[image]

Created on 2018-08-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to do it without ggplot?

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it possible to create the last plot in line (like second)?

Comment: @BeautifulMind: Sorry that's the best I can do. I haven't used base R for a long time :)

Comment: @BeautifulMind: you should really consider using `ggplot` for producing plots. It has many feature/extension and great support. See its extension gallery here http://www.ggplot2-exts.org/gallery/

Answer (score 1):

In `ggplot`, we assemble the plot from layers connected with the plus operator `+`.

So we can start by defining the dataset to plot (`data`), then use the `aes` function to specify which variables to use for the `x` and `y` axes. Finally we tell it to plot both points and a line using this data.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = data,
       aes(x = NodeID, y = pageRank)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() +
    xlab('Node Rank') + ylab('PageRank Value')
```

[image]

Simple! I highly recommend using `ggplot` whenever possible over the limited and obtusely designed `base R` graphics.